# How to create Accept and Cancel Buttons in C#, Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a Windows Form Application.

I have two buttons (Accept and Cancel) and I want to call the click event for one when Enter is pressed, and the click event for the other when Escape is pressed.

This is a code I've tried (I found it here on a similar question) that didn't work.

```
  protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter)) {
            this.btnOrder.PerformClick();
        }
         if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Escape))
         {
             this.btnCancel.PerformClick();
         }
    }
```

I have looked through all the properties and events of the buttons but I cannot find anything Accept or Cancel related. I know that this is probably way too easy but I've learnt of these buttons tonight and I just can't do them.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a property of the Form:

- [`AcceptButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`CancelButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton(v=vs.110).aspx)

In the Form Designer: You add the buttons to the form, select the form, and select the buttons you want as accept and/or cancel button.